# Passing data from directive to parent scope controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, maps

Ive created a directive which creates a google map on the page and all works fine.

What I want to be able to do is pass the map object back out of the directive into the parent controller so I can use it in my methods etc.

I know i could probably store it on some attribute but it seems wrong. Is there any way I can just pass the the object directly into it so I can use it whenever I like?

Thanks, James

Comment: You can use service to store the data. that service could be included into directive or any other controller.

Comment: I think I'm using the wrong approach and using a services would be best. I wont be able to access the data I need on init due to the load order of the directive but I should be able to access it on click for example which is when I need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a service first with Google Maps and then create a directive to use it.